# std convert uint16_t to string_view

Tags: c++17, string-view

I want to convert `std::uint16_t` to `std::string_view`. I was expecting the following code would work:

```cpp
std::string_view to_str(std::uint16_t v) {
    return std::string_view(std::to_string(v));
}
```

because it uses an intermediary `std::string` in `to_str` function scope.
I know I can use a static storage for intermediary string like this:

```cpp
std::string_view to_str(std::uint16_t v) {
    static auto str = std::to_string(v);
    return std::string_view(str);
}
```

I know there is another way to use `char buffer` and convert it to `string_view` but I wonder is there any better way to serve this very same purpose? Is it even logical to return `string_view` instead of `string`?

Comment: None of the solutions you have will work, but _why_ would you want a `string_view` when you create a `string` anyway? Once you _have_ the `string`, just use _that_.